# question about algorithm

Tags: two-column, algorithms

I'd like to ask how can have an algorithm(s) flow (like text) from one column to another in a two-column document? I don't want to treat it as a one block like a figure is treated.

Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

Comment: You can use `listings` or the `verbatim` package.

Answer (score 2):

As long as the algorithm is set using a package that manages it as a *list*, then it will be breakable across columns or page boundaries. If a package manages the algorithm in a box, then it won't break.

[`algorithmic`](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithms) and [`algorithmicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx) manages its algorithms inside lists, as can [`listings`](http://ctan.org/pkg/listings). Here's an example using `algpseudocode` from `algorithmicx`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}% http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry
\usepackage{algorithm,algpseudocode,caption}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{algorithms,algorithmicx,caption}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-5]
\captionof{algorithm}{Euclid’s algorithm}\label{euclid}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
  \Procedure{Euclid}{$a,b$}\Comment{The g.c.d. of a and b}
    \State $r\gets a\bmod b$
    \While{$r\not=0$}\Comment{We have the answer if r is 0}
      \State $a\gets b$
      \State $b\gets r$
      \State $r\gets a\bmod b$
    \EndWhile\label{euclidendwhile}
    \State \textbf{return} $b$\Comment{The gcd is b}
  \EndProcedure
\end{algorithmic}

\lipsum[6-10]
\end{document}
```

Note that the algorithm is *not* set inside the `algorithm` environment, otherwise it will be boxed and made to float. We circumvent the float-like caption outside of a float by means of `\captionof` from the [`caption` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/captionof).